# Which activate script does "conda activate xyz" call in Windows 10?

Tags: conda

I need to add some environment variables so a Python module finds its dependencies. I would like to do this during the activation of a virtual environment, but I could not figure out which script is called on `conda activate some_env` (Windows 10).

There are several scripts and I added some `echo` commands, but was not able to identify which one is used:

```
some_env\Lib\venv\scripts\common\activate
some_env\Lib\venv\scripts\nt\activate.bat
some_env\Lib\venv\scripts\nt\Activate.ps1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't mess with the scripts that `conda` has generated automatically. Instead, you can create a custom `.bat` script that sets the required environment variables, see [the conda docs](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#windows):

1. Locate the directory for the conda environment in your Anaconda Prompt by running in the command shell `%CONDA_PREFIX%`.
2. Enter that directory and create these subdirectories and files:

---

```
cd %CONDA_PREFIX%
mkdir .\etc\conda\activate.d
mkdir .\etc\conda\deactivate.d
type NUL > .\etc\conda\activate.d\env_vars.bat
type NUL > .\etc\conda\deactivate.d\env_vars.bat
```

---

3. Edit `.\etc\conda\activate.d\env_vars.bat` as follows:

---

```
set YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE='whatever'
```

---

4. Edit `.\etc\conda\deactivate.d\env_vars.bat` as follows:

---

```
set YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE=
```

---

`etc\conda\activate.d` will be called upon activating the environment and `etc\conda\deactivate.d\` upon deactivating it

Alternatively, you can use `conda config` as described [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#setting-environment-variables) to set an environment variable specifically for an environment:

```
conda env config vars set my_var=value
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That works. Do you know something of the mechanics behind this? Probably related to the Linux udev rules? Some environment variables I need are set by another bat file some where on the system. Would this approach also be used to `call xyz.bat` in one of the scripts?